# Delete info based on the id provided

Tags: python

Lets say I've got some info in a txt file:

```html
id---username---password---email 
123456---student---password---student@gmail.com 
123456465---student---password---student@gmail.com 
123456---student---password---student@gmail.com 
51654645686---student---password---student@gmail.com 
123456---student---password---student@gmail.com 
1561654646--student---password---student@gmail.com 
123456---student---password---student@gmail.com
```

Now, if I want to delete the whole row based on the id, how do I do that? if the user input 123456, it should delete all those rows with 123456 as the id.

I've tried,

```html
user_input = input("Please enter the id")
with open(txt) as txt_read: 
  read = txt_read.readlines() 
  for line in read: 
    if line.split("---")[0] == user_input: 
      # then what
```

Comment: Read line by line, extract ID until separator, if match drop the line else keep by writing to new file. If needed replace old file by new one

Comment: @ mozway how do I code it?

Comment: You already know how to read a file, just do the same with `open(new_txt, 'w')` to write in the new one. Make sure to read a python file tutorial if you need background ;)

Answer (score 1):

this is alternative without creating new file :

```
user_input = input("Please enter the id : ") # id to delete
with open(txt, 'r+') as f:
    read = f.readlines()
    f.seek(0)     
    f.truncate()

    for line in read: 
        if line.split("---")[0] != user_input:
           f.write(line)
```

Comment: It removes all the info instead of that line with the id

Comment: please test it : https://www.mycompiler.io/view/4Kb5nWEncbA

Comment: @Jupri,,, I tested this code snippet and it works ;)

Answer (score 0):

This should work. Feel free to tweak it to your taste

```
user_input = input("Please enter the id")
save_file = open(text, "a")
with open(txt) as txt_read: 
  read = txt_read.readlines() 
  for line in read: 
    if line.split("---")[0] == user_input: 
      read.remove(line)
[save_file.write(i) for i in read]
save_file.close()
```

Comment: It removes all info

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).